# Why this type of power function work?

Tags: c, loops

```
res = 1;
for ( i = 1; i <= n; i <<= 1 ) // n = exponent
{
    if ( n & i )
        res *= a; // a = base
    a *= a;
}
```

This should be more effective code for power and I don't know why this works.

First line of for() is fine I know why is there i <<= i. But I don't understand the line where is: if ( n & i ). I know how that works but I don't know why...

Comment: what is `a` ? please try to explain your question better

Comment: Did you try to add a `printf` in the loop to see the values of the variables? http://ideone.com/NJtt4i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say you have a binary representation of an unsigned number. How do you find the decimal representation?

Let us take a simple four bit example:

```
N = |   0     |    1    |    0    |    1    |
    -----------------------------------------
    | 2^3 = 8 | 2^2 = 4 | 2^1 = 2 | 2^0 = 1 |
    -----------------------------------------
    |    0    |     4   |    0    |     1   |  N = 4 + 1 = 5
```

Now what would happen if the base wasn't fixed at 2 for each bit but instead was the square of the previous bit and you multiply the contribution from each bit instead of adding:

```
N = |   0   |  1  |  0  |  1   |
    ----------------------------
    |   a^8 | a^4 | a^2 |  a^1 |
    ----------------------------
    |   0   | a^4 |  0  |  a^1 |  N = a^4 * a^1 = a^(4+1) = a^5
```

As you can see, the code calculate a^N